# How to open Microsoft Edge from a Script?

Tags: python, microsoft-edge

I've been doing a little python practice and lately noticed I can't seem to open Microsoft Edge from python2.7 using `webbrowser` when it is my default browser. It instead opens the tabs in IE. Is there a reason for this? Is there a workaround?

Here's some sample code:

```
import webbrowser as web
from random_words import RandomWords

def main():
    rw = RandomWords()

    for i in range(0, 30):
        word = rw.random_word()
        web.open(word, new=0)

main()
```

Comment: You may be able to answer this yourself by looking at the `webrowser` module's [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/webbrowser.py).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` downloaded from [Microsoft WebDriver Downloads page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads), under 'Downloads' the current Release 14393, Version: 3.14393 | Edge version supported: 14.14393.  Either place that driver executable in the same directory as the script, or point the `webdriver.Edge` to the path it's downloaded to. Then this should work as expected:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser as web
from random_words import RandomWords

# create new Edge session
dir = 'C:\Users\Me\Downloads' # use os.path.dirname(__file__) if same directory as script
edge_path = dir + "\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(edge_path)

def main():
    rw = RandomWords()

    for i in range(0, 30):
        word = rw.random_word()
        driver.get(word, new=0)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import (Program Directory to .exe Here) as web
from random_words import RandomWords

def main():
    rw = RandomWords()

    for i in range(0, 30):
        word = rw.random_word()
        web.open(word, new=0)

main()
```

Comment: import program dir here as web
from random_words import RandomWords

def main():
    rw = RandomWords()

    for i in range(0, 30):
        word = rw.random_word()
        web.open(word, new=0)

main()

Comment: What is the syntax on importing a .exe directly like that? I believe `import C:$path as web` and `import "C:$path as web` are both invalid syntax

Comment: sorry, latter example was supposed to be `import "C:$path" as web`